# how to set h264 profile to main or high in kurento?

Tags: webrtc, kurento

Is there a example to change the h264 profile from baseline to main or high? I can see multiple profiles are supported from https://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/stable/knowledge/h264.html but can't find any information or settings to actual configure it?